# Ejecutar una consulta SQL en función php

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo dos archivos, en uno llamo una función y en el otro ejecuto la función que realiza una consulta SQL, pero no me funciona... que podrá ser?

```
$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "usuario_bd"; 
$password = "pass_bd"; 
$bdname = "bd_name"; 

 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $bdname);
 
 // Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) {   die("Connection
 failed: " . $conn->connect_error); }
 
 
 function conexiones(){
 
  $sql_conexiones=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from conexiones");
  $rs_conexiones=mysqli_num_rows($sql_conexiones); 
  echo $rs_conexiones;
  
  }
```

Al ejecutar `conexiones();` en otro archivo,  no me arroja resultados.

Comment: A tu función le tienes que declarar tu varable ```$conn```, añade esto al principio ```global $conn;```,

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo cambiarte a PDO para facilitar las cosas. Intenta usar esta plantilla para la conexión a la base de datos y para la consulta a la tabla conexiones.

```
<?php 
    class Connection {

        function connectdb() {

            //attributes

            $username = "usuario_bd"; 
            $password = "pass_bd"; 

            global $connect;

            //methods

            // Set DSN

            $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mibasededatos;';

            //Create a PDO instance

            try {

                $connect = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

            }catch(PDOexception $e) {

                print 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                
            }

        }

    }

    $newconnection = new Connection();
    $newconnection->connectdb();

    function bringConexiones(){
        //Bring the confirmed authorizations 
        $bringConexiones = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM conexiones");
        $bringConexiones->execute();
        $saveConexiones = $bringConexiones->fetchAll();
        print_r($saveConexiones);
    }
    bringConexiones();
    ?>
```